# Spring boot azure keyvault refresh on demand

Tags: spring-boot, azure-keyvault

I am using spring boot with azure's keyvault

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

but there is a problem, when I want to update secret.
How to force for example via rest api lets say, refresh of this value ?

```
@Value("${x-value}") private val xValue: String = "0"
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you rephrase you're question to clarify what exactly do you want to refresh? If you want to refresh the value from AKV (AKV secret changes -> value in code changes) you need to use environment to get the property:

```
@Autowired
Environment environment
...
xValue = environment.getProperty("x-value");
```

because @Value() is set during construction of the component. It won't change during it's lifetime.

If you want the change the AKV contents: this is not the purpose of azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets.